# FileNotFoundException exception in Windows 8 metro app

Tags: exception, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, filenotfoundexception

I just want to save some string into the local folder in a metro app, the code goes:

```
public GroupedItemsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        async private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("news.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "test");
        }
```

But always got an FileNotFoundException exception, I'm creating a file instead of getting a file, so I don't know what's wrong with this code snippet.

Could anybody show me how to fix this problem? Thx in advance.

Comment: Code works for me no problem.

Comment: @Jeff Brand Hi, Jeff. The code seems to be the right way, but it just caused an exception in my project. And I spent times finding the solution, with no result.

Comment: What version of Windows do you use RC or RTM?

Comment: @Vitaliy, everything goes well after I reinstall the Windows 8.